# MongoDB Schema for ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to build a mongoDB schema to represent ranking range for a game application where.

```
Rank 1 : 1000 Points
Rank 2 : 500 Points
Rank 3 : 250 Points
Rank 4-10 : 50 Points
Rank 11-15 : 25 Points
```

later after the game completes the points will be allocated according to above schema, everything is complete in my application except this,I am completely blank about implementation of this, I have tried this though & don't know if it is right way.

```
{
contestId : 98787676
entry_Points : 250 Points
MaxNoOfPlayers : 25
MinNoOfPlayers : 10
ranks : [
 {rank : 1, points : 1000},
 {rank : 2, points : 500},
 {rank : 3, points : 250},
 {rank : 4-10, points : 50}
 {rank : 11-15, points : 25}]
}
```

here in this as i assume i can access upto 3rd Ranks easily. can anyone suggest any better way of doing this if this is best way pls suggest how will i access 4-10 or 11-15 ranks ranks and allocate them to individual players.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but maybe I understand.  In your ranks[], you could specify the min and max within the range.

```
ranks : [
 {minrank : 1, maxrank: 1, points : 1000},
 {minrank : 2, maxrank: 2, points : 500},
 {minrank : 3, maxrank: 3, points : 250},
 {minrank : 4, maxrank: 10, points : 50}
 {minrank : 11, maxrank: 15, points : 25}]
}
```

Comment: for your better understanding, this is a game where a player is charged some amount of points from wallet as an entry fees then after game finishes we get ranks of each player .....now i need to allocate points to players wallet according to their ranks. the issue is there can be 1,000,00 players in a contest with even a player with 25,000 rank can get some points so i am allocating points to players in ranges. The points will allocated to the type of contest......this schema i am stuck with is that.

Comment: i liked your answer , will try to implement , if successfully will mark it as an answer for others, thanks for your valuable time.